# convert quantity textbox to drop down list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i convert this text box to a drop down list which has values 1-99 using jquery with the default item of 1 selected?

```
<input type="text" maxlength="4" size="3" onkeyup="if(typeof(getShipping) == 'function'){getShipping()}" onchange="if(typeof(getShipping) == 'function'){getShipping()}" id="Quantity" name="Quantity" value="1">
```

Answer (score 1):

Straightforward: Create a new `select` element, append `option` elements with values from 1-99, set attributes and `onchange` handler, then replace the `input` element with the `select`.

```
var select = $("<select>");
for (var i = 1; i <= 99; ++i) {
    select.append($("<option>").val(i).html(i));
}
select.val(1).attr({id: "Quantity", name: "Quantity"}).change(function(){
    if (typeof getShipping == "function") {
        getShipping();
    }
});
$("#Quantity").replaceWith(select);
```

[Test it here (JSFiddle)...](http://jsfiddle.net/Aletheios/w78G4/)